# TypeError while retrieving pool.apply_async() result

Tags: python, python-2.7, multiprocessing

## Question

I have an exception being raised that I cannot determine the cause of, and would appreciate help resolving it.

## Background

I have a pool of workers in Python 2.7.6 that I use to launch several functions asynchronously, and after closing and joining the pool, I check the ApplyResult objects to make sure all the functions were successful. When I try to retrieve the results, I get the following error:

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>     File "parse.py", line 798, in 
>       main()
>     File "parse.py", line 769, in main
>       produce_output_files(args.output_dir)
>     File "parse.py", line 524, in produce_output_files
>       print(result.get())
>     File "/user/Python-2.7.6/lib/python2.7/multiprocessing/pool.py", line 554, in get
>       raise self._value
>   TypeError: foo1() argument after ** must be a mapping, not AcquirerProxy

Here is my code for launching the subprocesses:

```
def produce_output_files(output_dir):

    pool = multiprocessing.Pool()
    manager = multiprocessing.Manager()
    db_lock = manager.Lock()
    results = [pool.apply_async(func, output_dir, db_lock) 
               for func in [foo1, foo2, foo3]]

    pool.close()
    pool.join()

    for result in results:
        if not result.successful():
            print(result.get())

    return
```

All of my target functions have the following structure:

```
def foo1(output_dir, db_lock):
    try:

        # wrapping the whole function in a try/except block because tracebacks
        # aren't pickleable, but they can be packaged into a string for pickling

    except:
        raise Exception("".join(traceback.format_exception(*sys.exc_info())))
```

## Debug Steps Taken

### Is it a Worker Exception?

Initially, I thought I was just getting a traceback from a worker because the [docs for AsyncResult](https://docs.python.org/2/library/multiprocessing.html#multiprocessing.pool.AsyncResult) state the following:

> If the remote call raised an exception then that exception will be reraised by get().

...and the way I'm packaging tracebacks into a single string should cause a proper traceback to be printed in the main process. To test this, I changed my called functions to this:

```
def _produce_C(output_dir, db_lock):
    raise Exception("test")
```

This test resulted in the same traceback, so I know I'm not printing an exception from the worker processes ("test" was never printed). I believe the exception is caused by how I'm retrieving the result rather than just the propagation of an exception from a subprocess.

### Result Not Ready?

I also know the result is ready by the time I call `get()` on the results objects because I've closed and joined the pool. Just to be sure of this, I changed my `for` loop to the following:

```
    for result in results:
        result.wait()
        if not result.successful():
            print(result.get())
```

This resulted in the same traceback as well.

### Workers Closed and Result Expired?

My last attempt to fix the error was to switch the order of the pool joining and retrieving the result like this:

```
    for result in results:
        result.wait()
        if not result.successful():
            print(result.get())

    pool.close()
    pool.join()
```

Again, the same traceback is produced.

## Other Information

As described in [this Python issue report](http://bugs.python.org/issue13831Ups), a full traceback will normally not be produced by the `get()` method because a traceback cannot be pickled. However, in my first debug test shown above, I should have still seen the string "test" in the traceback if `get()` was actually capturing the exception from the worker. Also, my method of wrapping the functions in `try`/`except` blocks to capture tracebacks is specifically mentioned as a workaround in the issue report I linked to.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to pass the arguments to the function you're calling with `apply_async` [in a tuple](https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/multiprocessing.html#multiprocessing.pool.AsyncResult):

```
results = [pool.apply_async(func, (output_dir, db_lock)) 
               for func in [foo1, foo2, foo3]]
```

That will fix the exception. Consider that this is the definition of `apply_async`:

```
def apply_async(self, func, args=(), kwds={}, callback=None):
```

Passing it arguments the way you currently are, you're really doing this:

```
pool.apply_async(func, args=output_dir, kwargs=db_lock)
```

Which explains the traceback:

```
TypeError: foo1() argument after ** must be a mapping, not AcquirerProxy.
```

It's trying to treat `db_lock` like `kwargs`. Definitely not what you want!

Comment: D'oh! You are exactly correct that I just left off the tuple. No matter how many times I use a function, sometimes the details get forgotten.